# How to add "New Document" option to desktop context-menu?

Tags: nautilus, desktop-environments, context-menu, document

I want to create any new document templates in desktop area **not only in folders**. When we add our templates to Templates folder in Ubuntu 20.04 it adds automatically "New Document" option to folders context-menu? But not to desktop!

Can't find solutions or extensions. How can I do this? With terminal or any extensions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Desktop Icons NG (DING)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) extension. It is an enhanced and maintained fork of the [Desktop Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/) extension that comes preinstalled with Ubuntu.

The extension provides the *New Document* option that you want. Other features include (quoting from the [extension's GitLab page](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng)):

> - Drag'n'Drop, both inside the desktop, between desktop and applications, and nautilus windows
> - Allows to use "Open with..." option with several files
> - When hovering or clicking on an icon with a name too large to fit, it shows the full name
> - Doesn't hang the compositor when there is too much activity in the desktop folder

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me.

Comment: @AKINCAN You're welcome!